Is it ever possible to solder at an interior point in a stainless steel shift cable?
Attempting to solder a stainless steel shift cable at an interior point, with the objective of subsequently cutting it cleanly is, as I've now found out, "non-trivial".
(One thread from the original tip quickly started unraveling during a rear derailleur cable redo, yet most of the cable remains perfectly usable for the front derailleur. But inserting a homemade cut is prone to fraying, even with the use of a serious cable cutter.)
Is it ever possible to solder at an interior point in a stainless steel shift cable?
I might possibly get away with a plain cut before inserting in the housing (notwithstanding that a new cable does arrive with a conspicuous tiny drop of solder). But being able to solder the inner portion of a shift cable means that I would never encounter fraying at the bolt, even if (when) I need to rebolt.
Related

How to cut a brake/derailleur cable?
How to prevent the derailleur cable fibres getting all over the places?


Wait, what do you mean by “interior point of a shift cable”? You mean soldering somewhere along the length instead of at the very end (so that you can cut it at this inline solder joint)? Regardless, this might be a better question for one of the metalworking, fabrication, or engineering SEs.

He's not heating the cable up enough to burn the oil off the inside windings and I'll guess he's not using flux either.

Are you trying to splice a cable together with solder at a point that will be inside the cable housing?

@DavidD My wording must have not been careful. Let me try again. After taking a new, newly installed, rear derailleur inner cable out (because I had omitted a part), I wasn't able to reinstall it again. It frayed and the fraying spread. But I don't want to just throw it out. Half of it remains perfectly usable for the front derailleur, which is my next task. Rather than cut first and then solder, I figured that a safer solution is to solder first and then cut. The cut would then hopefully be just as good as the one from the factory, complete with a soldered tip.

If you want to cut a cable cleanly, one trick is to use a short length of sacrificial housing over the cut. That prevents fraying fairly well, IME

@PaulH That's a nice hint. I'll experiment. The trouble is that inserting a piece of sacrificial housing will also be prone to fray one thread in the cable, but at least I'll see what's happening.

Soldering a stainless steel cable is hard - the metal rejects solder unless its clean and fluxed, and quite hot.
Instead, invest in some good quality bypass cable cutters where the blades pass closely.  You don't need knipex-price, something like this is ample:

One clean cut, then a drop of cheap superglue on the tip to hold it together while fitting.  Once fitted, trim again to length and crimp on a ferrule.
If the individual wires untwist themselves, just twist them back together on the cable.  Its not hard and can be done with the fingers - I've never cut myself doing this with a new clean cut.  Trying to re-lay an old cut is no fun, because the wires tend to be bent and not want to lay down.
Soldering worked great with plain steel cables, back before they were commonly galvanised.   For modern cables, its not a good solution.

Aww hell, that's industrial 101 stuff. lol. Not hard but as I said, not needed..
I use Ideal side cutters. Butter, as they say.

@somedumbguy not industrial - this is a $10 tool, and makes cable cutting easy forboth inner and outer.   Side cutters mash the blades against each other, whereas this slides the blades past, more like scissors.

The main jaws, I understand. What are the other features? Down by the spring, I think I see some crimpers, but I have no clue on the outside notches, the hole, or the big cylinder by your thumb.

@Michaelcomelately the two notches and the hole would be more ways to cut wires.  I've never used them.  The bumps are indeed for crimping cable ends, but they're a bit rubbish and I use a proper ferrule crimper now.  The cone thing, I don't have that on mine, can't picture what it might be for.

Sure. There's no reason to, but if needed it would be fairly trivial.
Get yourself a pencil torch, some acid flux and a little silver soldier.
soldier the cable before you cut it.
Are you having trouble getting the cable through the housing without messing it up?
Get yourself a sharp Awl or something like it and carefully open up the ends of the housing before trying to run the inner wire.

A blunt awl works just as well for opening up the housing (e.g. after cutting it) if not better as it won't cut the lining

No, it doesn't. But then again, dull tip doesn't hurt as bad when you stab yourself, and I have.

From talking to an engineer-turned-yuppy-hardware-store-salesperson, it appears you got exactly the right criterion. The keyword here is silver solder. It must be a silver alloy/amalgam to attach to any stainless steel (and all inner Bowden cables are SS). Waiting for comments confirming/refuting this before check-marking this answer.
